# BigQuery structure to track orders over time

Tags: google-bigquery

Just getting started with BigQuery (and big data/BI in general) and have a few questions about how to track orders over time given append only.

Let's say I have an online store/ecomm site and associated data.  We sell widgets.

As my orders progress through "created", to "shopping", to "completed" to "confirmd" (by vendor) to "fulfilled"/"shipped" and sometimes to "canceled"/"declined" (by vendor), how can I account for that in BigQuery such that I can build visualizations for "orders created but not completed", "orders fulfilled in date range" (somehow being able to account for those that were completed but canceled/declined by the vendor after completed)

Would I populate different tables with "Created orders" and "Fulfilled Orders" and "Canceled Orders" or is there some other mechanism to account for this given that I cannot update rows (change from completed to canceled).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Normally BigQuery comes with the dataset containing the ga_sessions tables (if you have the premium account). Do you have this dataset in your account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below as an example of how to parse events table for meaningful info:
This example is using BigQuery Standard SQL, so you need to uncheck `Use Legacy SQL` checkbox under <kbd>Show Options</kbd>

```
WITH order_events AS (
  SELECT 1 AS orderID, '2015-01-01' AS ts, 'created' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS orderID, '2015-01-01' AS ts, 'shopping' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS orderID, '2015-01-02' AS ts, 'completed' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS orderID, '2015-01-03' AS ts, 'confirmed' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS orderID, '2015-01-04' AS ts, 'shipped' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS orderID, '2015-01-01' AS ts, 'created' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS orderID, '2015-01-01' AS ts, 'shopping' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS orderID, '2015-01-02' AS ts, 'completed' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS orderID, '2015-01-03' AS ts, 'declined' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS orderID, '2015-01-01' AS ts, 'created' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS orderID, '2015-01-01' AS ts, 'shopping' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS orderID, '2015-01-02' AS ts, 'completed' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS orderID, '2015-01-03' AS ts, 'confirmed' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS orderID, '2015-01-04' AS ts, 'shipped' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS orderID, '2015-01-01' AS ts, 'created' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS orderID, '2015-01-01' AS ts, 'shopping' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS orderID, '2015-01-02' AS ts, 'completed' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS orderID, '2015-01-03' AS ts, 'confirmed' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS orderID, '2015-01-05' AS ts, 'canceled' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS orderID, '2015-01-01' AS ts, 'created' AS event UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS orderID, '2015-01-01' AS ts, 'shopping' AS event 
),
order_history AS (
  SELECT 
    orderID, 
    (SELECT STRING_AGG(events, ' > ') FROM t.events) AS history
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      orderID, 
      ARRAY(SELECT event FROM t.events ORDER BY ts ASC) events 
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        orderID, 
        ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(event, ts)) events
      FROM order_events 
      GROUP BY orderID
    ) t
  ) t
)
SELECT *
FROM order_history
#WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(history, r'((?:created).*(?:canceled))') IS NOT NULL
```

Result of above visualize order history as

```
orderID     history  
1           created > shopping > completed > confirmed > shipped     
2           created > shopping > completed > declined    
3           created > shopping > completed > confirmed > shipped     
4           created > shopping > completed > confirmed > canceled    
5           created > shopping
```

Now, if you will uncomment last line with `WHERE` clause - you will get only orders that match given pattern - in this case: orders that were created but than canceled.

```
orderID     history  
4           created > shopping > completed > confirmed > canceled
```

Setting proper Regexp gives you flexibility for any filter for needed analysis

Hope this gives you an idea and you can extend this to your specific needs !

Answer (score 1):

Two tables for you:

`order` and `order_events`

In the order you create the order data, and in the events table, you store anything after the order. The events table will have an `event` column that can describe what action did encountered.

And regarding queries, you simply join the two and return the one that you are interested in.